# AddThis Share : LinkedIn always open in new window

Tags: linkedin-api, addthis

We're using AddThis Social Share functionality with our Sitecore/MVC application. The problem we're facing is that the LinkedIn share always opens in new window. On Inspect, we can see the

```
target=_blank
```

in code, which is not being added in our code.

Any help?

Thanks,
Chandana

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? Having the very same problem here.

Comment: Hi elvismdev,  we didn't find a solution to it and had to live with it. I had sent an email to the AddThis support team and they needed some sort of support term with them, most probably a license purchase to look into the issue. So, we explained the same to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of each share button is as per the website to which the page is being shared. If you test each button (say Facebook, G+, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.) you will notice that they all work differently. It's not AddThis choice. This is because each website has its own API and that's the way that website decided it would work with their system. LinkedIn happens to open a separate window... Pinterest first opens a popup within your page and then another window after you selected the image you wanted to share. G+ and Facebook open a new tab. And the popups/windows all look quite different, but the users should recognize each respective brand as a result...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a problem with the *AddThis Social Share functionality*.  To share on LinkedIn, all you need is the following URL format...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Then you can setup your `<a href="...">` element however you like, with `target="_blank"` or not.

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

Answer (score 0):

Can try out below JavaScript code, which will overwrite addthis functionality, and make linkedIn as popup,

setInterval make sure click event  attached to dynamically generated anchor tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var clickinterval = setInterval(setclickevent, 500);
            function setclickevent() {
                if ($('.at-svc-linkedin').length > 0) {
                    $('.at-svc-linkedin').on('click', function () {
                        window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=' + fixedEncodeURIComponent(window.location.href), 'popup', 'width=600,height=600');
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
                    clearInterval(clickinterval);
                }
            }
            function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
                return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
                    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
                });
            }
        });
```